# How to pass arguments to a function when called by an array?

Tags: python

I have a function and I have an array of arguments that I want to pass to the function when calling it like this:

```
def function(arg):
    pass

function(arg)#call
```

but I want:

```
target = function
args = list()
output = call(function,args)
```

I know, that I can do it with Thread, but I want get a return to main Thread

```
Thread(target=target,args=args).start() # without output :(
```

The only possible solution I have come up with is

```
output = exec('function_name('+','.join(args))
```

P.S. The functions that I call have a variable number of positional and optional arguments

P.P.S. I can't edit function's code

Answer (score 1):

If those are positional arguments you can use `function(*args)`.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Оказывается, это было так просто...

Comment: Glad that helped @teodoroven. Remember to upvote / mark question as answered if the answer is correct.